# AssertEqual fails on comparing two identical int objects

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit test cases for a method that returns an integer indicating the first element & last elements from a list of nodes. When i run it, using dummy data, the tests fails, but the value is same and so is the data type. What am i missing?

**The Original Method**

```
def foo(transitions):
    sources = set(transitions["from"])
    destinations = set(transitions["to"])

    # Find Start
    # <Code to Find Start>

    # Find End
    end = destinations - sources
    if bool(end):
        end = list(end)  
    else:
        end = list(destinations)  
    end.sort(reverse=True)
    end = end[0]
    return start, end
```

**The Test Method**

```
    def test_foo_end(self):
    dummy_end = 4
    dummy_transitions = pd.read_csv("TestData/Transitions.csv", index_col=0)
    test_end = foo(dummy_transitions)
    print(type(dummy_end))
    print(type(test_end))
    self.assertEqual(self, test_end, dummy_end)
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
FF..
======================================================================
FAIL: test_foo_end (__main__.classTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class_UT.py", line 51, in test_foo_end
    self.assertEqual(self, test_end, dummy_end)
AssertionError: <__main__.classTests 
testMethod=test_foo_end> != 4 : 4
```

Comment: `assertEqual(self` <- What's that `self` doing there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.assertEqual(self, test_end, dummy_end)
```

is wrong.  Use

```
self.assertEqual(test_end, dummy_end, "some descriptive message")
```

Otherwise you will end up comparing `self` with `test_end` which will always be false.

The output you got also states exactly this:

```
AssertionError: <__main__.ModelProcessorTests
testMethod=test_find_boundaries_end> != 4 : 4
```

It says, "AssertionError" and then prints `a != b: c` with

- `a` being the lengthy term `<__main__.ModelProcessorTests testMethod=test_find_boundaries_end>` (which was `self`),
- `b` being `4` (which was `test_end`) and
- `c` being the message you gave (the value of `dummy_end` which was `4`).